# Google App Script: UrlFetchApp.fetch Address unavailable error

Tags: google-apps-script, jira-rest-api

I wrote following code in google app script.  When I run this code, it gives "Address unavailable: https://gsd.jira.com/jira/rest/api/2/issue/ (line 30, file "Code")"

```
function myFunction() {
  var header =
  {
    "Cookie":"JSESSIONID=82AEF41778F3036829323019EB7437C4",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  };
  var data = 
  {
    "fields": {
      "project":
      { 
        "key": "TEST"
      },
      "summary": "REST ye merry gentlemen.",
      "description": "Creating of an issue using project keys and issue type names using the REST API",
      "issuetype": {
        "name": "Story"
      }
    }
  };
  var options =
  {
     "headers" : header,
     "method" : "post",
     "payload" : data
  };
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://gsd.jira.com/jira/rest/api/2/issue/", options);
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());
}
```

However, when same HTTP request was created using "REST Console" chrome extension, it worked successfully and created a jira issue.

What is wrong with this code?

Comment: It looks like `gsd.jira.com` doesn't exist. I can't ping it.

Answer (score 0):

Host gsd.jira.com doesn't exist (try http://www.dnswatch.info/dns/dnslookup?la=en&host=gsd.jira.com&type=A&submit=Resolve).
It seems "gsd.jira.com" is address on your computer or local network specified e.g. via hosts file or local DNS server. When you use apps script, you are accessing the target API endpoint from Google servers.
If your API interface is not public, you can not access it froom apps script.